# Show that if $\sum_0^\infty a_kx^k$ has radius of convergence $R>1$ $a_k$ is bounded. What about R=1?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to show that if:

$\sum_0^\infty a_kx^k$

Has a radius of convergence $R>1$. $\{a_k|k\in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded. What about the case $R=1$?

Here is how I start. Since the series converges in particular the series: $\sum_0^\infty a_k $ converges so there is a $k_0$ such that if $k>k_0$ $|a_k|<M$. Now the rest of the series $\sum_0^{k_0-1}a_k$ converges so $a_k$ for $k<k_0$ has to be bounded as well. Correct so far?

The case for $R=1$. Now $\sum_0^\infty a_kx^k$ converges when $x<1$. I don't think $a_k$ is bounded now, but how to show it?

Comment: @bof Sorry, faulty translation. Yes, radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already remarked,
if $R>1$ then the series is convergent for $x=1$, i.e. $\sum_k a_k$ is convergent.
Hence $\lim_k a_k = 0$. But a convergent sequence is always bounded.

If $R=1$, it is enough to consider the case $\sum_k k x^k$ as a counterexample.